# 2sxc Use Same Data Set between 2 instances of same module but different App Settings per Instance

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I've created a 2sxc App that creates a list of items. Each item can have 1 of 3 statuses (Pending, Inactive, and Active) I've added a setting to the app settings to toggle if the app will show Pending, or Inactive Items, or Active Items. As these item's statuses get updated (Pending > Active > Inactive) I want the items to stop showing in one instance of the app and show in another. Following the advice in this answer [How to force two instance of the same app (DNN/2sxc) to read from the same stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42349666/3295493) I created a copy using the DNN Add Existing feature. This links the Data between the instances, however it also links the App Settings. So I am unable to set one to Active and one instance to Pending.

How would I go about doing this, or is this possible?

Comment: Current workaround is in App Settings to provide string settings for entering the part of the url for the page that should show active, url for page that should show pending, etc. This isn't great... but works as a hot fix until there is a "Correct" answer that works available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think your making it to complicated. From what I understand, you have different views which should show different items based on a filter.

If that's what you're doing - just create another view (pointing to the same template file) and give it another visual-query filtering by that property.

Make sense?